Ansible, Custom Fact - 'VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: ''ogg_fact_general'' is undefined
Ansible custom facts, defined in /etc/ansible/facts.d. I can get their values manually just fine, like so:
[root@lnx000 templates]# ansible lnx072  -m ansible.builtin.setup | grep ogg_fact
                "ogg_fact_general": {
                    "ogg_fact_bu_name": "UPTER",
                    "ogg_fact_environment_type": "VAR",
                    "ogg_fact_home": "/goldengate",
                    "ogg_fact_next_depl_iterator": "114",
                    "ogg_fact_service_manager_port": "9000",
                    "ogg_fact_version": "21c"

However, I am having trouble passing lets say an "ogg_fact_version" as a variable within a playbook. For comparison, I put in a test "ansible_distribution" fact, which is not custom, of course. That one shows just fine in a debug. But not what I am after, the "ogg_fact_version" I defined myself.
The playbook:
---
- hosts: ogg_servers
  become: yes
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:

  - debug: var=ansible_distribution

  - debug: var=ogg_fact_version

  - name: Generate a GoldenGate Response File for the oggca Utility to Create a New Deployment | Add a GoldenGate Deployment
    template:
        src: /etc/ansible/templates/oggca.rsp.j2
        dest: /tmp/ogg_add_depl.rsp
        owner: oracle
        group: oinstall
        mode: '0775'

The output (see the "UNDEFINED"):
[root@lnx000 ansible]# ansible-playbook ./playbooks/depl.yml

PLAY [ogg_servers] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [lnx072]
ok: [lnx000]
ok: [lnx001]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [lnx000] => 
  ansible_distribution: OracleLinux
ok: [lnx001] => 
  ansible_distribution: OracleLinux
ok: [lnx072] => 
  ansible_distribution: OracleLinux

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [lnx000] => 
  ogg_fact_version: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
ok: [lnx001] => 
  ogg_fact_version: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
ok: [lnx072] => 
  ogg_fact_version: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [Generate a GoldenGate Response File for the oggca Utility to Create a New Deployment | Add a GoldenGate Deployment] ************************************************************************************
ok: [lnx072]
ok: [lnx000]
ok: [lnx001]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
lnx000                     : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
lnx001                     : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
lnx072                     : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

[root@lnx000 ansible]# 

My long term goal is to use the "ogg_fact_version" as partial string in the name of the destination template file.
dest: /tmp/ogg_add_depl_{{ ogg_fact_version }} {{ ogg_fact_environment_type }}.rsp
But first, of course, I need to make sure it is passable as a variable to Ansible, which cannot use the "ogg_fact_version" as it is not defined as the built in fact "ansible_distribution".
Please help with both issues.
Thanks
I expected to see the "ogg_fact_version" from within the playbook, just as the manual ansible run shown here:
ansible lnx072  -m ansible.builtin.setup | grep ogg_fact

Managed to resolve on my own:
---
- hosts: ogg_servers
  become: yes
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:

  - debug: var=ansible_distribution

  - name: print ansible_local
    debug: var=ansible_local

#  - name: print book title
#    debug: msg="The Oracle GoldenGate version on this server is {{ ansible_local.ogg.ogg_fact_version.ogg_fact_version }}"

  - name: Generate a GoldenGate Response File for the oggca Utility to Create a New Deployment | Add a GoldenGate Deployment
    template:
        src: /etc/ansible/templates/oggca.rsp.j2
        dest: /tmp/ogg_add_depl_{{ ansible_local.ogg.ogg_fact_general.ogg_fact_version }}.rsp
        owner: oracle
        group: oinstall
        mode: '0775'

